# Spring Security Oauth2 Client get access token fails with invalid request code=415, message=Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

Using Spring Boot, I've set up an `Oauth2RestTemplate` bean in a configuration class and the appropriate properties in the properties file. I have used Swagger codegen to create the client stub. When I attempt to call the RESTful API, Spring fails on getting an access token with the root cause being "unsupported media type". Below is the stacktrace, my Spring Security client config, and my attempts to fix. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Retrieving token from https://dev-api.some-domain.com/auth/oauth2/v1/token
ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider.doWithRequest - Encoding and sending form: 
{grant_type=[client_credentials], scope=[read], client_id=[val from props], client_secret=[val from props]}

error="access_denied", error_description="Access token denied.
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:142)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.client.ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider.java:44)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:148)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.createRequest(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:735)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:651)
    at com.my.co.service.holidays.client.invoker.ApiClient.invokeAPI(ApiClient.java:518)
    at com.my.co.service.holidays.client.api.HolidaysApi.getHolidays(kHolidaysApi.java:183)
    at com.my.co.service.holiday.HolidaysApiTest.getHolidaysTest(HolidaysApiTest.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:686)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:212)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:137)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
**Caused by: error="invalid_request", error_description="{code=415, message=Unsupported Media Type}"**
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.deserialize(OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.deserialize(OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.java:33)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4524)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3519)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:269)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:249)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport$AccessTokenErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:782)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:740)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:695)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:137)
    ... 75 more
```

Below is my configuration for the Oauth2 client

```
application.properties:
spring.security.oauth2.holiday.client.clientId=valid_key_is_here
spring.security.oauth2.holiday.client.clientSecret=valid_secret_is_here
spring.security.oauth2.holiday.client.accessTokenUri=https://dev-api.some-domain.com/auth/oauth2/v1/token
spring.security.oauth2.holiday.client.clientAuthenticationScheme=form
spring.security.oauth2.holiday.client.grantType=client_credentials
spring.security.oauth2.holiday.client.scope=read
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class SpringOauthRestClientConfig {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.security.oauth2.holiday.client")
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oAuthDetails() {
        return new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(oAuthDetails());

        for (HttpMessageConverter converter : restTemplate.getMessageConverters()) {
            if (converter instanceof AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                ObjectMapper mapper = ((AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter) converter).getObjectMapper();
                mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
            }
        }
        // This allows us to read the response more than once - Necessary for debugging.
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(restTemplate.getRequestFactory()));
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

I have tried extending the Spring class `ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider` to provide my own implementation of the `obtainAccessToken()` method so I can set the Content-Type in the header. Then I inject my custom class into the RestTemplate. Still get the same error when Spring tries to get the access token.

```
public class ClientCredentialsCustomAccessTokenProvider extends ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider {

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken obtainAccessToken(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details, AccessTokenRequest request) throws UserRedirectRequiredException, AccessDeniedException, OAuth2AccessDeniedException {
        ClientCredentialsResourceDetails resource = (ClientCredentialsResourceDetails)details;

        HttpHeaders headers1 = new HttpHeaders();
        headers1.add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        return retrieveToken(request, resource, this.getParametersForTokenRequest(resource), headers1);
    }
```

If I use Postman to hit the authorization server, I successfully get back a token

```
{
    "tokenType": "BearerToken",
    "expiresIn": "899",
    "accessToken": "dv6fnhBALtNzlhjMyCRfa9JDYodd"
}
```

using these settings in Postman

```
POST request, 
Authorization - Basic with my client_id/secret as username/password, 
Headers - Content-Type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded, 
Body - grant_type = client_credentials
```

In JUnit test, I can set the token value (and bypass the Spring injection of `RestTemplate`) using the response from Postman and call the service without issue.

```
HolidaysApi api = new HolidaysApi();
OAuth oAuth2 = (OAuth) api.getApiClient().getAuthentication("OAuth2");
oAuth2.setAccessToken("dv6fnhBALtNzlhjMyCRfa9JDYodd");
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Spring is using the `FormHttpMessageConverter` class under the covers to prep the http POST request to the auth server and it appends to the Content-Type header "charset=UTF-8". The authorization server I'm hitting doesn't allow anything other than the Content-Type it's expecting (application/x-www-form-urlencoded). There may be another way, but I ended up using my own `CustomFormHttpMessageConverter` that sets the Content-Type correctly into the `OAuth2RestTemplate` bean. Below, I'm showing things in reverse order:

Essentially copied the Spring `FormHttpMessageConverter` class and created a custom class, changing the `writeMultipart()` method to set the Content-Type without the character set:

```
public class CustomFormHttpMessageConverter implements HttpMessageConverter<MultiValueMap<String, ?>> {
  ...
  writeMultipart(...) {
      ...
      outputMessage.getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    }
}
```

Then, you need to use your custom message converter class:

```
public class CustomOAuth2AuthTokenCallback implements RequestCallback {

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
private final MultiValueMap<String, String> form;
private final HttpHeaders headers;

protected CustomOAuth2AuthTokenCallback(MultiValueMap<String, String> form, HttpHeaders headers) {
    this.form = form;
    this.headers = headers;
}

public void doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
    request.getHeaders().putAll(this.headers);
    request.getHeaders().setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));
    if (this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        this.logger.debug("Encoding and sending form: " + this.form);
    }
    CustomFormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new CustomFormHttpMessageConverter();
    formHttpMessageConverter.setCharset(null);
    formHttpMessageConverter.setMultipartCharset(null);
    formHttpMessageConverter.write(this.form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED, request);
    }
}
```

Now, we need to make sure our custom callback is used:

```
public class ClientCredentialsCustomAccessTokenProvider extends ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider {
@Override
protected RequestCallback getRequestCallback(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, MultiValueMap<String, String> form, HttpHeaders headers) {
    return new CustomOAuth2AuthTokenCallback(form, headers);
    }
}
```

I had a custom location in the properties file for the client info, so I used:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.security.oauth2.holiday.client")
public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oAuthDetails() {
    ClientCredentialsResourceDetails details = new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    return details;
}
```

So now we have our provider bean with a custom token callback. All we need at this point is to tell the rest template which provider to use:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class SpringOauthRestClientConfig {
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oAuthDetails) {
    OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(oAuthDetails);
    restTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(new 
    ClientCredentialsCustomAccessTokenProvider());
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(restTemplate.getRequestFactory()));
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Instead of going through all that just to get a token for Basic Auth using client credentials, I ended up going this route (using `HttpEntity<String>`):

```
String url = "https://some-domain.com/auth/oauth2/v1/token";
String credentials = "some-client-key:some-client-password";
String encodedCredentials = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(credentials.getBytes()));
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_HTML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>("grant_type=client_credentials", headers);
ResponseEntity<Oauth2Token> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, request, Oauth2Token.class);

boolean isSuccess = response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful();
HttpHeaders respHeaders = response.getHeaders();
Oauth2Token body = response.getBody();
```